# Javascript function not loading in Django template

Tags: javascript, django

I have a HTML tag  that is supposed to run a function in my javascript file (app.js) when it gets clicked (this is implemented using the onclick tag property)
but instead I get the following error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: summon_chat is not defined at HTMLLIElement.onclick`

But when in my javascript file (app.js) I code something like this it works:

```js
const list_item = document.querySelector('#listId')
list_item.onclick = function () {
    summon_chat()}
```

But if I don't use list_item.onclick in my app.js file and leave the function alone and assing it directly to the HTML tag using the onclick property  it doesn't work

```js
function summon_chat(chat){
  //logic 
 }
```

what am I doing wrong?
My base.html file is located at templates/layouts/
and my index.html is located at templates/

This is my index.html fragment that calls the function:

```
<li onclick="console.log('CLICKED'); summon_chat(this);" class="list-group-item p-3">
```

This is my base.html:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="light">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.10" integrity="sha384-D1Kt99CQMDuVetoL1lrYwg5t+9QdHe7NLX/SoJYkXDFfX37iInKRy5xLSi8nO7UC" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'app.js' %}" type="module"></script>
    {% block script %}{% endblock script %}
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <main>{% block content %}{% endblock content %}</main>
    </div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

I already checked the dev console in my browser and the javascript file is loading correctly, I even added a console.log at the beginning of my JS file and it prints in the console, I already deleted the browser cache like 20 times, I inspected the rendering HTML and there's nothing wrong, I already searched here for a solution, I already extended my base.html correctly in my index.html file, I already used {% load static %} in both my index.html and base.html.

Comment: Try moving the script tag with your function definition just before body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about the `type='module'` statement within your base.html.

When you add it as a module it can not interfere directly with the DOM or listen to events on your document due to scope isolation. You either want to remove the `type='module'`

```html
<script src="{% static 'app.js' %}"></script>
```

or you would want to add something that directly links your js function to the dom, as you already did in your question

```js
// Inside your module (app.js)
function myClickFunction() {
    console.log('Button clicked!');
}

// Attach the function to the window object to make it globally accessible
window.myClickFunction = myClickFunction;
```